# NSXMLParser RSS feed strange characters issue

Tags: iphone, xml

hi i am trying to loop through XML document using NSXMLParser and have trouble with description tag.

some news websites have strange characters(HTML tags,<,>,a etc) in the  tag and thus parsing is not as expected. could anyone provide some help?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert entity references to the characters that they represent. Any HTML tags would either need to be stripped, or fed into a UIWebView.

Comment: character are identified by the parser as '<''>' characters. any idea how to parse it before fed to xmlparser?

Comment: So each of the brackets is surrounded by single quotes? If that's the case you could always just replace all instances of '<' with < and '>' with > before sending to the parser.

Answer (score 0):

For skipping the html tags you need to do this:

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ; 

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
    }
    //
    html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return html;
}
```

Then you can simply replace other unwanted characters by string manipulation.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, strange characters are inside the description tag (<description> text + strange characters</description>). in this case how do i pass the found text to your method. the problem is that the strange characters are been identified by XMLParser as '>''<' characters and sometimes parser is assuming end of tag eben if it is inside the description tag.

Comment: @likki please show the sample response you are trying to parse and also the part in which you are facing the problem.

Comment: <description>The market has been referring to the problem nations in Europe all year as the PIIGS. But maybe it should be the piigS.&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/rss/money_topstories/~4/mgzttHYMi9s" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>